# GET http://localhost/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php

In Php when I try to load the page and this error appears in the console:  GET http://localhost/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). ||  js and css don't work on my web page

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
```

but the path is correct,   even though i had a 404 problem...
what'the problem?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In CDN It worked, but in local files(downloaded files) not worked.

Comment: if the bootstrap.min.css is in the root folder, try by directly giving the filename without giving the root /